# PHP-FPM: 'No such file or directory' error from nginx/error.log. Path or permissions issue?

Tags: centos, permissions, php, nginx, mediawiki

I am getting a "FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to open primary script: /var/www/mediawiki/index.php (No such file or directory)"" error when I enter my wiki address in a browser bar. Here is my PHP-FPM www.conf file:

```
[www]
user = nginx
group = nginx
listen = /var/run/php/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock
listen.owner = nginx
listen.group = nginx
listen.mode = 0660
;chroot = 
;chdir = 
;env[HOSTNAME] = $HOSTNAME
;env[PATH] = /usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin
;env[TMP] = /tmp
;env[TMPDIR] = /tmp
;env[TEMP] = /tmp
php_value[session.save_handler] = files
php_value[session.save_path]    = /var/lib/php/session
php_value[soap.wsdl_cache_dir]  = /var/lib/php/wsdlcache
php_value[opcache.file_cache]  = /var/lib/php/opcache
```

Here is my nginx conf.d file:

```
# HTTP requests will be redirected to HTTPS

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    server_name wiki.example.com;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

# HTTPS Configuration

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    listen [::]:443;

    server_name wiki.example.com;
    root /var/www/mediawiki;

    index index.php;
    autoindex off;

    # SSL Certification Configuration

    ssl_certificate 
      /etc/letsencrypt/live/wiki.example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key 
      /etc/letsencrypt/live/wiki.example.com/privkey.pem;

    client_max_body_size 5m;
    client_body_timeout 60;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?title=$1&$args;
    }

    location ^~ /maintenance/ {
    return 403;
    }

    #PHP-FPM Configuration NGINX

    location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
    }

    location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
    try_files $uri /index.php;
    expires max;
    log_not_found off;
}

location = /_.gif {
    expires max;
    empty_gif;
}

location ^~ 
^/(cache|includes|maintenance|languages|serialized|tests|images/deleted)/ {
    deny all;
}

location ^~ ^/(bin|docs|extensions|includes|maintenance|mw- 
config|resources|serialized|tests)/ {
    internal;
}

# Security for 'image' directory
location ~* images/.*.(html|htm|shtml|php)$ {
    allow all;
    types {}
    default_type text/plain;
}

# Security for 'image' directory
location ^~ /images/ {
    allow all;
    try_files $uri /index.php;
}

}
```

I feel like it is a permissions issue or the php-fpm daemon is looking in a redundant file path or something. I tried passing an absolute path to FPM via the nginx conf.d file by doing:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/mediawiki/index.php;
```

to no avail. So I know I'm pointing it in the right direction but it still gives me the same error which makes me believe I have a permissions issue. I've also tried:

```
setenforce 0
```

but this also doesn't work. I've chmod 777 the entire directory up to and including the index.php file.

Some background:

I wanted to install a wikimedia extension which required a new version of php (7.0+) and I was running 5.4 since it came with the base install of CentOS 7. I wasn't familiar with how to update PHP so I accidentally yum remove php*, installed php73 from remi, removed that, re-installed php 5.4, and finally figured out I could yum update with remi-php71.repo enabled to update my base packages. However, I lost my .conf and php.ini files in this process.

Edit:

/var/log/nginx/error.log when I go to my website in a browser:

```
2019/01/22 16:58:19 [error] 10876#0: *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Unable to 
open primary script: /var/www/mediawiki/index.php (No such file or 
directory)" while reading response header from upstream, client: 
10.11.190.1, server: wiki.example.com, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock:", host: 
"wiki.example.com"
```

/var/log/php-fpm/www-access.log:

```
- 22/Jan/2019:16:58:19 -0700 "GET /index.php" 404 
/var/www/mediawiki/index.php /var/www/mediawiki /index.php /index.php
```

Comment: Added nginx error log and php-fpm access log. Thank you!

Comment: Just tried it; same exact error in both php-fpm access log and nginx error log.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it, thanks to Christopher for pointing me in the right direction with his query about `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` in **php.ini**.

His specific question did not fix the issue, but I continued to play around with settings near `cgi.fix_pathinfo=0` in **php.ini** and was able to get a different error message with NO error from PHP-FPM complaining about not being able to open `/var/www/mediawiki/index.php`.

This problem took me a solid 5 days to resolve. I REALLY appreciate the help Christopher!

I ended up commenting the following lines in **php.ini**:

```
;cgi.fixpathinfo=0
;user_dir=/var/www/mediawiki    **This is the one that changed the error message
```

Once I changed that, I got a `InvalidArgumentException` which was due to me not installing `php-mysqlnd` when I upgraded from 5.4 > 7.1.

Once I installed that, bam, wiki is back up and running.

I feel like running around the building five times. Thanks again to Christopher for pointing me in the right direction!

Jordan

Comment: Yes I was bummed there wasn't more information in the error logs and/or fpm access logs. I already had the logs set to 'debug' -- the highest output verbosity available. Thanks again for your help Christopher.